# Retrieve value from HTML Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following div (this was already given to me, I did not create it):

```
<div data-sudo-slider='{"slideCount":1, "moveCount":1, "customLink":"#slider-nav a", "continuous":true, "updateBefore":false, "effect":"sliceRevealDown", "auto":true, "speed":1500, "pause": 5000}'>
```

as far as my understanding goes (please correct me if I am wrong), we are saying here, that I want to assing the following values (such as slideCount, moveCount, customLink, etc...) to the object named `data-sudo-slider`.

What I am trying to do in my underlying JavaScript, is to retrieve the value of `pause` from this object. Here is what I am doing:

```
var sudoEl = jQuery('[data-sudo-slider]'); 
var pause = sudoEl.pause;
```

Even though it recognized the slider object, it did not retrieve the value for pause I have passed in (returned value is `undefined`.

How can I retrieve this value?

Comment: Beginner's answer worked. why did you have to specify 'sudoSlider' only for your data? How come this worked? (also, please make it as an answer)

Comment: does my comment work?

Comment: no uzaif, it dit not; it has returned `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) like this:

> The **.data()** method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM
>   elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore
>   from memory leaks. We can retrieve several distinct values for a
>   single element one at a time, or as a set:

```
$('[data-sudo-slider]').data('sudoSlider').pause;
```

> **why did you have to specify 'sudoSlider'?**

You can also use `sudo-slider`.

It worked as the property name is derived as following:

1. The attribute name is converted to all lowercase letters.
2. The data- prefix is stripped from the attribute name.
3. Any hyphen characters are also removed from the attribute name.
4. The remaining characters are converted to CamelCase. The characters immediately following the hyphens removed in Step 3 become uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the correct element use

```
var element = $("div[data-sudo-slider]");
```

You can either get the *data-sudo-slider* attribute via

```
var sudoSlider = element.attr("data-sudo-slider");
```

In which case you will have to convert the string to JSON to access the pause property:

```
var pause = JSON.parse(sudoSlider).pause;
```

or better yet, use the `.data()` method

```
var sudoSlider = element.data("sudoSlider");
var pause = sudoSlider.pause;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) to fetch `data-sudo-slider` value.

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the jQuery collection, as set by `data(name, value)` or by an HTML5 `data-*` attribute.

```js
var sudoEl = jQuery('[data-sudo-slider]').data('sudo-slider'); 
alert(sudoEl.pause);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-sudo-slider='{"slideCount":1, "moveCount":1, "customLink":"#slider-nav a", "continuous":true, "updateBefore":false, "effect":"sliceRevealDown", "auto":true, "speed":1500, "pause": 5000}'>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Comment: Also, it's important to mention the side-effects of using `data` (in particular, that the generated object sticks around until the element is destroyed).

Comment: ^which will create memory leaks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this property by:

```
$(function () {
    var pause = $('[data-sudo-slider]').data('sudoSlider').pause;
});
```

`$('[data-sudo-slider]')` is the div element, where `data-sudo-slider` is defined. `.data('sudoSlider')` is the data property value. `data` is working with `-` signs a littlebit different, you can read about it in [jQuery data documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

`.pause` is the property of `JSON` object.